# Calling c dll method in c#

Tags: c#, c

I am getting error as "'Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Non-blittable generic types cannot be marshaled.'"

in C code I have

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pch.h"
typedef void(*RECV_CALLBACK)();
RECV_CALLBACK pfRecvCallBack;

typedef void(*RECV_CALLBACKINT_PARA)(int);
RECV_CALLBACKINT_PARA pfRecvCallBackIntPara;
extern "C"
{
    

__declspec(dllexport) void MethodWith_INT_Para(RECV_CALLBACKINT_PARA pfIntPara)
    {
        if (pfIntPara)
        {
            pfRecvCallBackIntPara = pfIntPara;
        }
    }
    __declspec(dllexport)  void MethodWithNo_Int_Para(RECV_CALLBACK pfRecv)
    {
        if (pfRecv)
        {
            pfRecvCallBack = pfRecv;
        }
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void Calling_INT_PARA(int a, int b)
    {
        pfRecvCallBackIntPara(a + b);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void Calling_without_Para(int a, int b)
    {
        pfRecvCallBack();
    }
    
}
```

When i try to call this in C# call back without int parameter is working fine, but the callback with int parameter(line ->MethodWith_INT_Para(testWithIntPara);)  is giving error as mention above.

C# code

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("Sample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "MethodWithNo_Int_Para")]
static extern void MethodWithNo_Int_Para(Action ptr);
[DllImport("Sample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "MethodWith_INT_Para")]
static extern void MethodWith_INT_Para(Action<Int32> ptr);
[DllImport("Sample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Calling_INT_PARA")]
static extern void Calling_INT_PARA(int x, int y);
[DllImport("Sample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Calling_without_Para")]
static extern void Calling_without_Para();
Console.WriteLine("After calling Declare");
MethodWithNo_Int_Para(testWithoutIntPara);
Calling_without_Para();
void testWithoutIntPara()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Without int para : called by Calling_without_Para");
}
MethodWith_INT_Para(testWithIntPara);
Calling_INT_PARA(1, 3);
void testWithIntPara(int x)
{
   Console.WriteLine("With Int Para {x} : called by Calling_INT_PARA");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I am using Action to define callback function, please let me know if there is any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Action<int>` is generic, which cannot be marshalled. You need to create a custom delegate. Another problem is that C is expecting a function with the CDecl calling convention, bu the default is StdCall.

You need to use the following types, instead of `Action` and `Action<int>`

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.CDecl)]
public delegate void ActionCDecl();

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.CDecl)]
public delegate void ActionIntCDecl(int p1);
```